Error: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200 con GULP
El código siguiente crea un archivo .h pero cuando lo trato de llevar al navegador la página no muestra nada, y en consola solo aparece el error net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200
function toH(pathname) {
    return gulp.src(pathname)
        .pipe(flatmap((stream, file) => {
            const filename = path.basename(file.path);
            const wstream = fs.createWriteStream(`../ESP32_platformio_v2/src/webh/${filename}.h`);
            wstream.on('error', (err) => {
                console.error(err);
                stream.emit('error', err);
            });

            const data = file.contents;
            wstream.write(`#define ${filename.replace(/\.|-/g, "_")}_len ${data.length}\n`);
            wstream.write(`const uint8_t ${filename.replace(/\.|-/g, "_")}[] PROGMEM = {`);
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (i % 1000 === 0) wstream.write("\n");
                wstream.write(`0x${('00' + data[i].toString(16)).slice(-2)}`);
                if (i < data.length - 1) wstream.write(',');
            }
            wstream.write("\n};");
            wstream.end();

            return stream;
        }));
}

A continuación muestro la función que está llamando el archivo .h
    if (security){
        if (!request->authenticate(device_user, device_password))
            return request->requestAuthentication();
    }
    AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse_P(200, dataTypeHTML, index_html_gz, index_html_gz_len);
    response->addHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    request->send(response);
}

Y lo siguiente es la función que crea el archivo .gz
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gulp.src('../front/*.htm*')
            .pipe(htmlmin({
                removeComments: true, 
                collapseWhitespace: true, 
                minifyJS: true, 
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyURLs: true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
            .pipe(gzip({ append: true }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
            .on('end', resolve)
            .on('error', reject);
    });
}

Como referencia dejo esto https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer?tab=readme-ov-file#send-binary-content-from-progmem
